# What does "properly conditioned" means in this context in Herstein's "Topics in Algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm going through the 1.2 Mappings section, self-studying, and right after lemma 1.2.1 about the associative law to the composition of mappings of sets to other sets, he goes on to say

> We should like to show that if two mappings $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are properly
> conditioned the very same conditions carry over to [the compostion] $\sigma \circ \tau$.

He didn't define "properly conditioned" before, nor does he define it shortly thereafter. I suspect that what he means is along the lines or surjectivity. Can anyone sharea thought? Thanks

Comment: It is not a concept, it is the authors' style of saying "adding appropriate conditions". They use it many times throughout the book. The lemma that follows adds some conditions to $\sigma$ and $\tau$ and proves the same condition on $\sigma\circ\tau$. Not any condition would have worked. So, they called them "proper".